# How to open browser for testing with DBUnit in CakePHP?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, testing, dbunit

I'm using CakePHP and DBUnit for database testing. What I'd like to achieve is to test whether the form I've submitted on the website, inserts the data correctly into the DB. I have now a lot of UI tests, where I test the page itself, but I've only this small amount of DB test:

```
<?php

class testSchema extends PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase {

    /*
    ** @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DB_IDatabaseConnection
    */
    public function getConnection() {
        $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=job_manager;host=localhost','root','toor');
        $pdo->exec("set foreign_key_checks=0");
        return $this->createDefaultDBConnection($pdo, 'job_manager');
    }

    /*
    ** @return PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_DataSet_IDataSet
    */
    public function getDataSet() {
        $cascadeTruncates = true;
        return $this->createMySQLXMLDataSet(dirname(__FILE__).'/default.xml');
    }

    public function testRowCounts() {
        $this->assertEquals(3, $this->getConnection()->getRowCount('jobs'));
        $this->assertEquals(1, $this->getConnection()->getRowCount('machines'));
        $this->assertEquals(4, $this->getConnection()->getRowCount('users'));
    }

}
?>
```

I've tried to do something like this:

```
$this->setBrowser('*firefox');
$this->setBrowserUrl('url');
$this->open('link');
```

Like I did in the UI tests, but it doesn't work (because this class is inherited from PHPUnit_Extensions_Database_TestCase and not from PHPUnit_Extensions_SeleniumTestCase)

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution at the end (maybe it can help someone later):

At the end I've created a bash script, and execute a UI test and a DB test after that. Also I had to modify the DB class such that:

```
public function getDataSet() {
    $cascadeTruncates = true;
    return $this->getConnection()->createDataSet();
}
```

So now it gets the dataset from the current DB.